# whatching changes in a shared object with inotifytools

Tags: shared-libraries, inotify, dlopen

A part of my program is compiled to a libsomething.so (shared object). I kind of want to track, when changes to that library have been made, so that my main program can reload the file, when required. Therefore I thought inotifytools might be a good idea since I heared that it has a solid wrapper for inotify.

init:

```
inotifytools_initialize();
inotifytools_watch_file("./libsomething.so", IN_ALL_FLAGS);
// stripped error handling for clarity
```

loop:

```
if (struct inotify_event *event = inotifytools_next_event(0)) {
    println(inotifytools_event_to_str(event->mask));
    [reload function pointers from shared object]
}
```

but for some reason I only get one event after the first recompilation of type IN_ATTRIB (Metadata changed). I don't get IN_DELETE, IN_CREATE or IN_MODIFY. And nothing after the first event. I have the feeling I am nearly killing myself doing this with inotify.

The question here is not necessarily: "how do I do this with inotify(tools)?" it is rather "is inotify the right approach to do it or is it overkill and there is a simpler solution for this problem". Before I used inotify I simply checked the file system on file changes, but that got me into the trouble that my program wanted to reload the file, before it was completely rewritten by the compiler. I thought I would avoid this issue nicely (and easy) with inotify, when I only listen to the right events.

Answer (score 0):

> I kind of want to track, when changes to that library have been made, so that my main program can reload the file, when required.

On most modern UNIX systems, modifying a library that is *in use* is a *really bad idea*, and will more likely than not cause your application to crash.

The only sane way to update such library is to

1. Remove it from disk (if it's still in use, its reference count will not drop to 0, and it will still be kept), and
2. Create a new (updated) copy in its place.

> I simply checked the file system on file changes, that got me into the trouble that my program wanted to reload the file, before it was completely rewritten by the compiler

You appear to be doing the library update the *insane* way. It doesn't matter how you detect changes -- you'll get in trouble one way or the other. To understand why, think about how [demand paging](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Demand_paging) works.

Comment: So when I do a system upgrade, all my programs are updated while they are in use. And it never made any problems at all. In fact that is the one really nice thing that I always liked about the linux environment. So you mean, when I open a library with dlopen and then recompile it (override it) it makes a lot of problems? I checked what the build system exactly did, and it doesn't change the file, it deletes it and creates a new file with the same name.